# Difficulty Setting Up Hierarchical Sidebar On TypeDoc Generated HTML Docs Site

Tags: typescript, documentation-generation, typedoc, custom-theme

Typedoc has been helpful for generating a static website from inline doc comments (tsdoc standard), but it has an issue where it lists the entry points all in one column instead of grouping theme

First, I tried to install the hierarchical theme "https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-theme-hierarchy", but it had an issue where it set the root of the project to my D: drive instead of the actual root directory. It also seemed to have some issues finding the documentation pages I wished to open.

Here is my typedoc config:

```json
{
  "out": "docs",
  "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"],
  "excludeExternals": true,
  "excludePrivate": true,
  "excludeProtected": true,
  "hideGenerator": true,
  "includeVersion": true,
  "disableSources": false,
  "entryPointStrategy": "expand",
  "entryPoints": ["pages", "lib", "config", "components"],
  "tsconfig": "./tsconfig.json"
}
```

And here is a screenshot of part of the documentation page
[image]

All I want is that the theme should have a sidebar that looks like the following

```
clusterclicker -v0.1.0
    components
        core
            CardModal
            ConfirmDialog
            FaIcon
            Hr
            Page
            SimpleDrawer
            SteppedInput
        project
            FileNavigator
            Hotbar
            ImageView
            MaskingTools
            annotation-tools
                DotTool
    

etc.
```

Comment: Try with the [typedoc-theme-hierarchy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typedoc-theme-hierarchy) plugin